# Displaying Unicode in the WPF Webbrowser Control

Tags: wpf, unicode, webbrowser-control

I am trying to display unicode characters in an html string in the WPF WebBrowser control and it doesn't appear to be working.  I am using the following html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Łuk zwykły</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have set the IE Emulation to IE 11 (11000) and set the default characterset:

```
 DirectCast(CurrentWebBrowser.Document, IHTMLDocument2).defaultCharset = "UTF-8"
```

The file is in UTF-8 yet this is what is displaying:

Åuk zwykÅ‚y

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the encoding in the HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: I could have sworn I already tried this but it works now.  Thanks!